# Resizing items in a statusbar - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expression-blend

How can I arrange the items on a statusbar uniformly? Because when I run the project and maximize the window, all the items are placed on the left most corner.

```
 <StatusBar Grid.Row="3" Background="#FFDED9D9"  Grid.ColumnSpan="9" Margin="2,29,0,1"  >


<Label Content="Running"/>
<Separator >
</Separator>
<Label Content="           " />
<Separator>
</Separator>
<Label Content="Object" />
<Separator>
</Separator>
<Label Content="Status:" />
<Rectangle Height="19" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="18"    Fill="#FFFFFDFD" >
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" ScaleX="-1"/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
<Separator> </Separator>
<Button Content="Show" Height="25.96" Width="117.113" ></Button>
<Separator> </Separator>
<ProgressBar Value="55" Height="20" Width="85"  ></ProgressBar>

        </StatusBar>
```

Comment: Please write a better title based on your specific problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Any other answers please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an UniformGrid as template, it is made for that. Everything in the Statusbar will align automatically. You don't need to specify column ids for that. You might need to take out those separators.

```
<StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>

    <Label Content="..." />
    <Label Content="..." />
    <Label Content="..." />
    <Label Content="..." />
</StatusBar>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a Grid to the StatusBar and add as many columns as needed with their widths set to *

```
<StatusBar>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" />
        <Label Grid.Column="1" />
        <Label Grid.Column="2" />
        <Label Grid.Column="3" />
    </Grid>
</StatusBar>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I have already included 8 column grids each of width = 50 for the menu items in the menu bar. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Pallavi - I don't understand, why would adding a grid to the status bar be a problem when you have a grid in the menu bar? Some UIs have lots of grids.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for each label and button then u ll get alignment uniformly

```
 HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
```